# What does the output current depend on in the booster circuit?

Tags: voltage-regulator, boost, step-up

What methods are there to increase the output current of the booster circuit?

I got the figure below from a [TI LMR62014](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr62014.pdf) step-up voltage regulator datasheet.

Assume Vin = 4 V and Vout = 8 V

In this case, when I choose the appropriate components (capacitor, resistor and inductor) will I have a maximum output current of 600 mA? Is it impossible to have an output current of 800 mA in these conditions? What should I do when I need more current at the output?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet shows what this regulator is capable of and it can provide 600mA at 4 V input and 8 V output.

If you need more current you need a different regulator that can provide it.